# Backend script passing data to client-side script

Tags: python, flask

Say that I have a Python Flask server running which has a backend script that produces a number and a string.

How can I pass the number and string from the backend to a script that runs of client-side so that the user can run it rather than the server?

Example:
backend script data_producer.py produces "asdaslkdjasdlksja" and 18 from its functions

I want to pass "asdaslkdjasdlksja" and 18 to a Brython or JavaScript HTML embed ( tag) so that it can be processed in the browser and the results be sent back to my server.

**Edit:** I realized that I can just use Jinja2's "{{ }}" when rendering a template so that I can use data in an HTML script embed

Comment: Using http request? Data you've provided is not enough to suggest you smth concrete.

Answer (score 0):

The question you asked is too broad. It's almost equivalent to asking, how you can connect two computers. Since you haven't even specified any data type, the first thing that comes to my mind is using `sockets` which is as low level as you can get.

*A more high level and appropriate approach would be to use an HTTP REST server (with flask-RESTful), since you already have a flask server running.*

However, there's another million ways to transfer data between two Python scripts, from WebSockets, WebRTCs, sshing, the new IPFS to even emails. Now most of them would probably be overkill, so I would suggest you to make a simple REST server and make the client send GET or POST requests to it.

*After looking at the new edit, I still think a REST api is the best option. Since you can easily make a GET or POST request using the `fetch` api in Javascript. In Brython you can use `ajax` to do the same thing.*